# massive files renaming in unix with date prefix

Tags: unix, while-loop, find, printf, mv

Hi I need a massive renaming for files like this:

"Some Text Here 01 December 2019.pdf" into this format: "2019-12-01 Some Text Here.pdf"

"Some Text Here" could be of different lenght and made up different words from file to file.

The text that I want to modify into numeric data I also want to delete ("01 December 2019")

How can I made a massive renaming for all the files with this format inside a directory?

Answer (score 1):

```
regex='^\(.*\)\s\([0-9]\{2\}\s\w\+\s[0-9]\{4\}\)\(\.[^.]*\)$' 
for old in *.pdf ; do
    old_name=`echo "$old" | sed -e "s/$regex/\1\3/"` 
    date_string=`echo "$old" | sed -e "s/$regex/\2/"`
    new="`date +'%Y-%m-%d' -d \"$date_string\"` $old_name"
    mv -v "$old" "$new"
done
```